# Can't spot the stack level too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm trying to do an variant of flatten, per example when having:

```
{a: {b:  1}}
```

I should get this

```
#=> {"a.b":1}
```

and so on

Here is my code:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
def pathifize(hash,results = {}, current_key='', b = ".")
  hash.each do |new_key, value|
    combined_key = [current_key,new_key].delete_if { |k| k.blank? }.join(b)
    if value.is_a?(Hash)
      pathifize(hash,results, combined_key, b)
    else
      results[combined_key] = value
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting stack level too deep while trying to testing out on Irb.

Comment: It's normal, your out-of-recursion check is `value.is_a?(Hash)`, but `pathifize` is called on an `hash`

Comment: _Sidenote:_ https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor is the gem that does (besides many other things) exactly what you want. You might take a look at it’s code for the inspiration.

Comment: @mdesantis Thanks, hmm i'm still getting => {:a=>{:b=>1}} do you have any idea on how to make it like => {"a.b":1}

Comment: @Arb yes I know, I tried it, but that's another issue and IMHO you should try to fix it by yourself before :) it's a good exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recurrent `pathifize` call takes original `hash` (and that's why for nested hashes it creates infinite recursion) as an argument, while it probably should take `value`:

```
pathifize(value, results, combined_key, b)
```

Comment: Thanks , hmm i'm still getting => {:a=>{:b=>1}} do you have any idea on how to make it like => {"a.b":1}